# Choice menu, choice from user in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cmd

So in my program in Java i have 4 class. I want to make a choice menu and depending on the user's choice to run the appropriate class. How can this happen?

It is a text based memory game. I want to run it in the CMD.

Comment: Consider using [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: My false i edit it, it is text based memory game

Answer (score 0):

You will create one more class which will have `main()` method. Let's call it a `Runner` class.

In the runner class, you will need to take input from user. Use `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` for the same.

After reading the user input,you can simply do a `switch case` or `if else` on the user input to instantiate an object for the chosen class. After instantiating,  call the respective method of that class using the instantiated object.

Let me know in comments if you need further help with the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easily maintainable, all the 4 classes should implement a common interface. `Runnable` in this example, where the `run()` method is the class entry point. In this example I have only 2 classes, but you can esaily extend it by adding elements to the `runnables` array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable [] runnables = { new M1(), new M2() };
        IntStream.range(0, runnables.length)
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + " " + runnables[i].getClass().getSimpleName()));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (choice >=0 && choice < runnables.length) {
            System.out.println("Your choice: " + runnables[choice].getClass().getSimpleName());
            runnables[choice].run();
        }
    }

    public static class M1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("I choose to run M1");
        }
    }

    public static class M2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("M2 was chosen this time...");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
0 M1
1 M2
0
Your choice: M1
I choose to run M1
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you shouldn't run classes rather take methods. In my Example I have 3 Classes, and in every class the Method "doSth":

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
String input = scanner.next();/*Get what the User types*/
switch(input){
  case '1':
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    c1.doSth();
    break;
  case '2':
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.doSth();
    break;
  case '3':
    Class3 c3 = new Class3();
    c3.doSth();
  default:
    System.Out.println('This Choice doesn't exist!');
    break;
}
```